# PHP add array element at the end of each element in an array

Tags: php, pdo

i have trouble figuring out how to merge the example below:

```
$postsArray = [];


***some query;
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);  

foreach ($result as $row) {

    $postsArray[] = [
    "externalPostId"=>$row[0],
    "numOfComments"=>$row[1],
    "numOfLikes"=>$row[2]
    ];

    ***another query;
    $topCommentsArray = [];

    $result1 = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

    foreach ($result1 as $row) {
       $topCommentsArray[] = [
       "commentId"=>$row[0],
       "externalPostId"=>$row[1],
       "numOfLikes"=>$row[2]
       ];
    };
}
```

what should i do in order to make the $topCommentsArray to be added as an array element at the end of each element in $postArray.

pay attention to the for inside for.

example:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["externalPostId"]=>
    string(17) "1234567"
    ["numOfComments"]=>
    int(0)
    ["numOfLikes"]=>
    int(0)
    array(5) {
      ["commentId"]=>
      string(7) "1234567"
      ["externalPostId"]=>
      int(10) 1234567
      ["numOfLikes"]=>
      int(0)
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["externalPostId"]=>
    string(17) "1235467"
    ["numOfComments"]=>
    int(0)
    ["numOfLikes"]=>
    int(0)
    array(5) {
      ["commentId"]=>
      string(7) "5634217"
      ["externalPostId"]=>
      int(10) 7654321
      ["numOfLikes"]=>
      int(0)
    }
  }
}
```

thanks for the help guys.

Comment: You appear to be overwriting the outer `$result` within the loop. Don't do that

Comment: You're also wiping out `$postsArray` each outer-loop iteration. How about you show an example of what you'd like the result to look like?

Comment: sorry typo in the writing here the code. will edit in a moment. and will add the result.

Comment: Also, this seems inefficient. Assuming the inner query is based on some data from the outer one, you could accomplish the same with a single query with appropriate joins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, which I think boils down to: How do I put `$topCommentsArray` in `$postsArray`?

The following will work:

```
<?php

$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);  

$postsArray = [];

// add a key so you can reference a single array
foreach ($result as $key => $row) {

    // use an array
    $postsArray[$key] = [
        "externalPostId"=>$row[0],
        "numOfComments"=>$row[1],
        "numOfLikes"=>$row[2]
    ];

    // sub query for comments
    $comments = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

    $topCommentsArray = [];
    foreach ($comments as $comment) {
       $topCommentsArray[] = [
           "commentId"=>$comment[0],
           "externalPostId"=>$comment[1],
           "numOfLikes"=>$comment[2]
       ];
    };

    // attach your comments to the array
    $postsArray[$key]['topComments'] = $topCommentsArray;
}
```

Comment: You need to reinitialize `$topCommentsArray` each time through the main loop, otherwise you'll append to all the previous comments.

Comment: THANK you so much @Lawrence Cherone it is exactly what i tried to achive !